# How does iPad determine that access point it is connected to is a phone with tethering?

Tags: tethering

When I connect my iPad to ordinary access point it shows a WiFi logo icon with radiating circles. But when I connect it to the access point which is a smartphone sharing its internet connection, it shows an icon of two chain links instead. Obviously, it determines somehow the type of the access point.

How? Where can I read more of this technology? How can I detect this myself on e.g. laptop running Linux?